# How to control how many times a function is run in a period of time?

Tags: java

I want to do this because if I don't `itemstack.damageItem(1, player)` gets called too often when clicking rapidly and the durability of this tool runs out too quickly.

```
@Override
public boolean itemInteractionForEntity(ItemStack itemstack, EntityPlayer player, EntityLivingBase target) {
         if (!target.worldObj.isRemote) {
        target.motionY = 0.25;

        float xDis = (float) (target.posX - player.posX);
        float zDis = (float) (target.posZ - player.posZ);
        float tangent = zDis / xDis;
        float angle = (float) Math.atan(tangent);

        float length = (float) 1;

        float xProj = (float) (length*Math.cos(angle)*Math.signum(xDis));
        float zProj = (float) (length*Math.sin(angle)*Math.signum(xDis));

        target.motionX = xProj;
        target.motionZ = zProj;

        itemstack.damageItem(1, player);
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I use Thread.sleep(200); it wants me to add a throw which in the end would mean I would have to change the base code or I would have to surround it with a try/catch (What does this do).

Comment: Is there a limitation to using Thread.sleep() in this section?

Comment: You cannot sleep / wait since that would just freeze the game while this code blocks.

Comment: @zapl what could I do insted?

Comment: **Why** do you think you want to pause the game in this method?

Comment: You don't have to add a throws.  You can wrap the Thread.sleep() with a try catch block and do nothing if an exception occurs.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson I want to do this because if I don't the game tends to double click instead of just once so the durability on the tool runs out too quick.

Comment: Then pausing the game is not what you want to do, you want to set a timestamp and check it against the `System.currentMills` and throw away any events that come in too fast/soon.

Answer (score 1):

### What you want to do is use is Rate Limiting

Here is an thread safe example implementation that has a function that part of its logic is rate limited using only JDK 1.7 Standard classes *( JSR305 annotations don't count against this as they should be in every project no matter what size!)*.

I show this approach to show that a simple solution can be had without additional dependencies. But using a prebuilt/pretested library is a much better approach.

*Guava and Guice are standard dependencies in pretty much all my projects so see below*

#### Relevant code excerpt from complete example [Q21866253.java](https://gist.github.com/jarrodhroberson/9084831)

```
@Override
public void functionToBeRateLimited(@Nonnull final String caller)
{
    // do some stuff every time here
    super.timesCalled.get(caller).incrementAndGet();

    // do some stuff only after a certain time has elapsed since the last time it was done
    if (shouldRun(caller))
    {
        // Your itemstack.damageItem(1, player); code would go here!
        System.out.println(String.format("%s Called Rate Limited Logic every %d ms", caller, DELTA));
    }
}

private Boolean shouldRun(@Nonnull final String caller)
{
    return currentTimeMillis() - LASTED_CALLED_BY_AT.get(caller).get() >= DELTA;
}
```

### Google Guava RateLimiter

If you need more sophistication and features or you need to Rate Limit a fair number of functions, I would just go ahead and use this.

This is more heavy weight because it uses Threads to keep from blocking the calling thread, but it is much more feature rich and flexible.

Both approaches have their place and time.

Google Guava [RateLimiter.java](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) JavaDoc

### Self Contained Complete Test Harness coded with multiple threads

The following Gist has a fully self contained ready to run test harness [Q21866253.java](https://gist.github.com/jarrodhroberson/9084831) of course you need the dependencies.
You could remove the JSR305 annotations, but you shouldn't really do that.

This includes a bonus Guava `RateLimiter` based implementation as well!

Answer (score -1):

This will stop the logic from being run more than once in a second:

```
private static Boolean shouldRun = true;

@Override
public boolean itemInteractionForEntity(ItemStack itemstack, EntityPlayer player, EntityLivingBase target) {
  if (shouldRun) {
    if (!target.worldObj.isRemote) {
        target.motionY = 0.25;

        float xDis = (float) (target.posX - player.posX);
        float zDis = (float) (target.posZ - player.posZ);
        float tangent = zDis / xDis;
        float angle = (float) Math.atan(tangent);

        float length = (float) 1;

        float xProj = (float) (length*Math.cos(angle)*Math.signum(xDis));
        float zProj = (float) (length*Math.sin(angle)*Math.signum(xDis));

        target.motionX = xProj;
        target.motionZ = zProj;

        itemstack.damageItem(1, player);
    }

    shouldRun = false;      

    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              shouldRun = true;
            }
        }, 
       1000 
    );
  }
}
```

If a second is too long, just change that 1000 there to 500 or something less.

Comment: or just store current time + 1000 as next allowed time, creating a thread is overkill.